# validate dynamic html forms with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

Here http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/17/ I created a two HTML forms and I would like to validate forms with javascript function. First it will be good to check if every required fields were filled in form. I need some universal check function because forms will be dynamic. I write something to check radio buttons. But I don´t know how to solve, if there will be other form.

```
var formValid = false;
function check(){
var radios = document.getElementsByName("first");
var i = 0;
while (!formValid && i < radios.length) {
    if (radios[i].checked) formValid = true;
    i++;        
}
if (!formValid) alert("error");
return formValid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/18/

```
var xyz = document.forms;
    for(var x = 0; x < xyz.length; x++){
        var list_of_nodes = xyz[x];
        for(var j = 0; j < list_of_nodes.length; j++){
            if(list_of_nodes[j].nodeName == 'INPUT'){
                var node = list_of_nodes[j];
                console.log(node);
                if(node.getAttribute('data-required') == "required" && (node.value == null || !node.checked)){
                    alert("error"); //replace this line with what you want to do if the form isn't filled
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

`document.forms` will return all the forms in the document so it doesn't matter if there is 1 or 51. then it just loops though the `childNodes` that are inputs and checks to see if they are required. If they are and they are not checked or have a null value (probably want to check it against empty string as well) then this will pop up an error.

Obviously this is rough but with one or 2 adjustments it should do the trick.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/B9r22/19/ I tried it, but also if I fill all require fields still appear alert, so do you know where is problem? ... and also I would like to check only form which I submited, not all forms in html